# How to move data from one column to another without overwriting existing values in destination column

Tags: excel, copy, paste

I'm hoping this is so simple I'm just over-looking the obvious answer!  I want to move the values (pictured) in column A, en-masse, to the blank cells in column B without overwriting the existing values in column B.  Note that the data in column B has differing number of rows.  Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3a9I.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew I was missing something...Copy Column A, highlight column B, 'Paste special', tick 'Skip blanks' checkbox and done!  Many thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to do this:

**Option 1**

- Place a filter onto the data
- Filter column B for blank values
- Enter a formula into B1 that is =A1
- Drag this down to the bottom of your cells
- Set the filter for all values
- Select the whole of column B
- Copy and Paste the data as values

**Option 2**

- Create a new column after B
- In this column enter the following formula - =IF(B1="",A1,B1)
- Drag this down to the bottom of your data
- Select the whole of column B
- Copy and Paste the data as values
- Delete column B
- Column C then becomes column B

Comment: Very many thanks...our answers 'crossed', I think I found my own solution and posted it too!

Comment: I didnt know about the Skip Blanks option, so I learnt something as well